# How to remove Y axis (hAxis) label/title from Google Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I read the API reference from google developer website. For material line chart, there is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) from [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts). Could anyone tell me how to remove the bottom "Month"? I think it should be worked by some code like:

```
hAxis: {
  title: ''
}
```

In addition, most of the hAxis and vAxis features don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is correct, the following option will remove the x-axis title...

```
hAxis: {
  title: ''
},
```

just be sure to use the options conversion method for *material* charts...

```
                         //convert options
materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(materialOptions));
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
      var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
      data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
      data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");

      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  5.7],
        [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7],
        [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12],
        [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.3],
        [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6],
        [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9],
        [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8],
        [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6],
        [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3],
        [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9],
        [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6],
        [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5]
      ]);

      var materialOptions = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        series: {
          // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
          0: {axis: 'Temps'},
          1: {axis: 'Daylight'}
        },
        hAxis: {
         title: ''
        },
        axes: {
          // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
          y: {
            Temps: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
            Daylight: {label: 'Daylight'}
          }
        }
      };

      var classicOptions = {
        title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
        series: {
          0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
          1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
        },
        vAxes: {
          // Adds titles to each axis.
          0: {title: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
          1: {title: 'Daylight'}
        },
        hAxis: {
          ticks: [new Date(2014, 0), new Date(2014, 1), new Date(2014, 2), new Date(2014, 3),
                  new Date(2014, 4),  new Date(2014, 5), new Date(2014, 6), new Date(2014, 7),
                  new Date(2014, 8), new Date(2014, 9), new Date(2014, 10), new Date(2014, 11)
                 ]
        },
        vAxis: {
          viewWindow: {
            max: 30
          }
        }
      };

      function drawMaterialChart() {
        var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
        materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(materialOptions));
        button.innerText = 'Change to Classic';
        button.onclick = drawClassicChart;
      }

      function drawClassicChart() {
        var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
        classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
        button.innerText = 'Change to Material';
        button.onclick = drawMaterialChart;
      }

      drawMaterialChart();

    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
     <button id="change-chart">Change to Classic</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

note: the conversion method will not work for all options,
many simply aren't supported...

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

another route would be to use a *classic* chart with the following option...

```
theme: 'material'
```